# Bootstrap DateTime Picker non-responsive

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a date / time picker from: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php

I created a test page which shows a text input and a calendar icon, but the page is unresponsive.  Nothing happens when typing in the text box or when clicking the icon.  Here is the HTML / JavaScript code for my test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../vendor/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script>
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
            format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
            autoclose: true,
            pickerPosition: "bottom-left"});
    </script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid ctnt">
        <form method="post" action="test.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <b>Test date / time</b>
                <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" /><br/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" class="btn-primary">
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Cancel" class="btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('Abandon any changes?')">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Update) I also tried this code for the picker:

```
        <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
            <input size="16" value="" type="text">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
```

...but it does not show any icon at all.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using the plugin is created for bootstrap 2

Comment: Oops, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6.

Comment: @Ismail Farooq Where are you getting the version information?

Comment: see the plugin bootstrap file

Comment: What do you mean by the "plugin bootstrap" file?  Do you mean the plugin JavaScript file?

Comment: no! if you see on inspect element there is a some css that comes from bootstrap.css if you see that file (bootstrap.css) you can see version

Comment: I don't understand what you are refering to.  What is the specific name of the file or URL of the web page that says the plugin is for Bootstrap 2?

Comment: See in the viewsource and find bootstrap.css and see its version

Comment: You misunderstand me.  I know how to find the version of Bootstrap I am using.  I just told you it is 3.3.6.  What I want to know is where it says that the Datetime plugin must use Bootstrap 2!

Comment: https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker?files=1 see here

Comment: You are wrong about the plugin being for Bootstrap 2 only.  On the page you just referenced there are links to samples in both Bootstrap 2 and 3.

Comment: Can you please make fiddle so i will figure out your actual problem